# How do I make use of LSP Code Action extensions?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I've been using neovim and lspconfig for quite some time. Today I noticed that some LSP servers have some sort of extensions, like extract variables and add constructor to the class, which lspconfig seems to not show when we do code actions. One example of that is phpactor which from their documentation they seem to have kind of cool features, like extract variable, but whenever I try to open code actions it just doesn't show those extensions.

My question is, does lspconfig support this kind of extension, or do I need to do something in order to see this kind of extension?